# I got an error while installing Web3 library in Python. Can anyone please help me?

Tags: python, blockchain, solidity

```
Building wheels for collected packages: lru-dict
  Building wheel for lru-dict (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [5 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'lru' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for lru-dict
  Running setup.py clean for lru-dict
Failed to build lru-dict
ERROR: Could not build wheels for lru-dict, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I have used command pip install `iru-dict`

I have updated pip to the latest version also

Comment: solved this issue by installing `wheel` : `pip install wheel`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use Anaconda to install python packages?
If you haven't, you can create new environment by using this bash script:

```
conda create --name myenv python=3.x
conda activate myenv
conda install -c conda-forge web3
```